# What is the mathematical meaning of this statement made by Gödel (see details)?

Tags: logic, incompleteness

It appears as Proposition VI, in  Gödel's 1931 paper ["On Formally Undecidable Propositions in Principia Mathematica and Related Systems I"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_Formally_Undecidable_Propositions_of_Principia_Mathematica_and_Related_Systems) :

> "To every $\omega$-consistent recursive class $\kappa$ of formulae there correspond recursive class-signs $r$, such that neither $v \, Gen \, r$ nor $Neg \, (v \, Gen \, r)$ belongs to $Flg (\kappa)$ (where $v$ is the free variable of $r$ )."

P.S. I know the meaning in plain English : "All consistent axiomatic formulations of number theory include undecidable propositions"

Comment: I do not understand the precise question. Can you go into more detail about what you are asking?

Comment: I encountered this in GEB book. I could not decipher the mathematical statement since, I have no background in logic. So, thought of seeking help here.

Comment: The reason I am confused is that you say you already know what the statement means, but you are asking what the statement means. If GEB is confusing, I recommend a different book. One good book, with clear explanations of the technical details, is "An Introduction to Gödel's Theorems" by Peter Smith. I do not recommend reading Gödel's original paper as a way of learning the theorems - although it is a fine paper, it has many issues that make it unsuitable for initial learning - the notation and terminology are two of these issues.

Answer (score 5):

See :

- Jean van Heijenoort, [From Frege to Gödel : A Source Book in Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=v4tBTBlU05sC&pg=PA592) (1967), page 592-on.

$\kappa$ is a set of ("decidable") formulas and $Flg(\kappa)$ is the set of *consequnces* of $\kappa$, i.e. the set of formulas derivable from the formulas in $\kappa$ plus the (logical) axioms by rules of inference.

[$\omega$-consistency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-consistent_theory) is a stronger property than *consistency* (that, under suitable conditions, can be replaced by simple consistency) [see van Heijenoort, page 596].

$Neg(x)$ is the *negation* of the formula (whose [Gödel number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering) is) $x$ :

> $Neg(x)$ is the arithmetical function that sends the Gödel number of a formula to the Gödel number of its negation; in other words, $Neg(\ulcorner A \urcorner) = (\ulcorner \lnot A \urcorner)$.

$xGeny$ is the *generaliation* of $y$ with respect to the *variable* $x$ :

> $Gen(x,y)$ is the arithmetical function (with two arguments) that sends the Gödel number of a variable $x$ and the Gödel number of a formula $A$ to the Gödel number of its universal closure; in other words, $Gen(\ulcorner x \urcorner, \ulcorner A \urcorner) = (\ulcorner \forall x A \urcorner)$.

In conclusion, under the $\omega$-consistency assumption, there is a (unary) predicate $P$ with Gödel number $r$ such that neither $\forall v P(r)$ nor $\lnot \forall v P(r)$ are derivable from the formulas in $\kappa$.

This means that the set $\kappa$ of formulae is *incomplete*.

See [Gödel's Incompleteness Theorems](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/).

See also this "modern" translation of Gödel's [original paper](http://www.ursuletz.com/cs150-fall2005/lectures/goedel.pdf).

Comment: I was reading the modern translation that you referenced. It says: "We will call a formula of PM with exactly one free variable of type natural numbers a class-sign. We will assume the class-signs are somehow numbered, call the $n$th one $R_n$..." Why are "class signs" countable? It doesn't sound clear to me.

Comment: @HowDoIMath - see [Gödel's Incompleteness Theorems](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/) : **2.3 Arithmetization of the Formal Language** : "First, the primitive symbols of the language are paired with distinct natural numbers, “symbol numbers”. A little number theory then suffices to code sequences of numbers by single numbers. Consequently, well-formed formulas, as sequences of primitive symbols, are each assigned a unique number. Finally derivations, or proofs, of the system, being sequences of formulas, are arithmetized, and are also assigned specific numbers." 1/2

Comment: "Such a code, the “Gödel number” of a formula $A$, is denoted as $\ulcorner A \urcorner$, and similarly for derivations." the symbols are finite in number, the expressions have finite lenght and the formulas are "effectively generated" by the recursive def of well-formed formula. Thus we can "effectively" list all wff by lenght and lexicographically. 2/2